# Problem in the proof that $S^n$ is a $n$-dimensional smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have the following definition:

**Definition:** $M\subset\mathbb R^{n+k}$ is a **$n$-dimensional submanifold of class $C^{p}$** of $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ if for every $x\in M$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ and a submersion $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb R^k$ of class $C^p$ such that $U\cap M=f^{-1}(0)$.

Recall $f$ is a **submersion** if $df_x$ is surjective for all $x$.

I'm trying to use this definition to show $$S^n=\{x\in\mathbb R^{n+1}: |x|=1\}$$ is a $C^\infty$ $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

**Up to now:** For every $x\in S^n$ taking $U=\mathbb R^{n+1}$ we have $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Furhtermore, the map $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $$f(x)=|x|^2-1$$ is $C^\infty$ in $U$. In fact, $1\in C^\infty(U)$ and (using multi-index notation) $$\displaystyle |x|^2=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 2} c_\alpha x^\alpha$$ for some $c_\alpha\in\mathbb R$, that is, $|x|^2$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ so that $|x|^2\in C^\infty(U)$.

I should be able to show $f$ is a submersion. But if I'm not wrong $$df_x(v)=2\langle x, v\rangle$$ and this  is not surjective for $x=0$. Did I miss something?

Finally, it is clear $U\cap S^n=S^n=f^{-1}(0)$.

The only problem is whether or not $f$ is a submersion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, $f$ is not a submersion. Now if you choose a different $U$...

Comment: Well, it suffices taking $U=\mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$.